# how to set value of an option by the value of another option in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

In the following example, I want to calculate/set the value of `leftright skip` automatically. How to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.6\textwidth]
      when the value of "left skip" is not given explictly, I want to set the value of "leftright skip" to (\textwidth - width)/2 automatically(implictly). What shall I do?
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: A little confused, are you try to center the tcolorbox?

Comment: For this example, yes. The general purpose is how to allocate the value of options. For example, how to know whether the option `1eft skip` has been given value explictly or not(the value of it is not 0pt?) and how to calculate lenghth value from the value of options(like \textwidth - `width`)/2).

Comment: What do you really want? Sth like "if `leftright skip` is not set, call option `center`, otherwise do nothing"?

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z Yes. My intention from this example are: (1) how to detect if an option is `explictly` given value or not? (2) how to call the value of an option(width, left skip ... etc)?

Comment: In general, no they're both impossible. `pgfkeys` doesn't have this utility. For example, with `leftright skip/.style={left skip={#1},right skip={#1}},`, calling `leftright skip=10pt` is indistinguishable from calling `left skip=10pt, right skip=10pt`.

Comment: `pgfkeys` doesn't let you do (1) in any straightforward way. You could get the functionality by doing something more complicated, but you'd either have to redefine the keys or use different ones. Re. (2): you can retrieve the values of some keys e.g. if you use a handler such as `.store`. You can also use things like `\pgfkeysvalueof` and `\pgfkeysgetvalue` but this won't return the value of the option in the general case, but the value stored in the key. At least, that's how I understand it.

Comment: You could, I guess, set a default value for `left skip` which you definitely won't use and then see if that has changed. You could also maybe use a `.forward` handler and test that to see if the value's been set.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a macro for `width`, and `\dimexpr` use that macro for `leftrightskip`. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newlength{\tcbwd}
\setlength{\tcbwd}{0.6\linewidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[leftright skip=\dimexpr(\linewidth-\tcbwd)/2,width=\tcbwd]
      when the value of "left skip" is not given explictly, I want to set the value of "leftright skip" to ($\backslash$textwidth - width)/2 automatically(implictly). What shall I do?
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how to detect if the option `left skip` is given value explictly or not?

Comment: @lyl Sorry, I don't know how to do it.